# How to load manifest.json in django from react build folder? manifest.json not found error

Tags: reactjs, django, manifest

Im developing a website using react bundled inside django servic static files. Everything appears to be working but my react is not working properly due to django not finding the manifest.json files.

I have tried a few solutions that i found here in StackOverflow:
mainly adding:

`path('manifest.json', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='manifest.json', content_type='application/json'), name='manifest.json')`

to my Django urls.py file and that worked to an extent, but then the error i get changes to:

`http://localhost:8000/logo192.png 404 (Not Found)`
`Error while trying to use the following icon from the Manifest: http://localhost:8000/logo192.png (Download error or resource isn't a valid image)`

I also noticed that the react favicon was not loading so I found a fix here for that by using:

`<link rel="icon" href="http://localhost:8000/media/favicon.ico" />`

instead of

`<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />`

Where the media folder is the folder im serving my urls.py file in django as my media root.

That got the favicon working but the logo192.png not found error still persists, but when I tried the same method for the png file i get the same error.

How do I fix it?